# Flexible textarea component with default width

Tags: html, css, styled-components

How to make textarea flexible component that will be:

1. With width = defaultMaxWidth but no more than 100% of parant size.
2. Editable, so i can change it's size by hand.

Here is my sandbox [attempt](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-snyder-u65f7?file=/src/App.js:315-330) (you can edit it), but it's has two problems:

1. Textarea size is restricted by defaultMaxWidth when trying to stretch it.
2. Textarea has problems with margins

Code:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Textarea = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper {...props}>
      <StyledTextarea ref={ref} {...props} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Centered>
      <Textarea
        height="300px"
        defaultMaxWidth="300px"
        placeholder="can't stretch"
      />
      <Textarea
        height="300px"
        defaultMaxWidth="3000px"
        placeholder="textarea is in parent size, but there is problems with my right margins!"
      />
    </Centered>
  );
}

const Centered = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;

const defPadding = 5;
const defMargin = 5;

const StyledTextarea = styled.textarea`
  margin: ${defMargin}px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  max-width: calc(
    ${p => p.defaultMaxWidth || "100%"} - ${defPadding * 2 + defMargin * 2}px
  );
  width: 100%;
  height: ${p => p.height || "100px"};
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: calc(
    ${p => p.defaultMaxWidth || "100%"} - ${defPadding * 2 + defMargin * 2}px
  );
  width: 100%;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix margins i need to set textarea max-width = 100% - padding * 2 + margin * 2.

To make it flexble, you need to use width as it is.

Here is the solution (sandbox updated):

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Textarea = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper {...props}>
      <StyledTextarea ref={ref} {...props} />
    </Wrapper>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Centered>
      <Textarea height="300px" width="300px" placeholder="can't stretch" />
      <Textarea
        height="300px"
        width="3000px"
        placeholder="textarea is in parent size, but there is problems with my right margins!"
      />
    </Centered>
  );
}

const Centered = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
`;

const defPadding = 5;
const defMargin = 5;

const StyledTextarea = styled.textarea`
  margin: ${defMargin}px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  max-width: calc(
    ${p => p.defaultMaxWidth || "100%"} - ${defPadding * 2 + defMargin * 2}px
  );
  width: ${({ width }) => width || "400px"};
  max-width: calc(100% - ${defPadding * 4}px);
`;

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
`;
```